# SQL query - Adding blank data for few columns

Tags: sql

Got below table structure.

**Table1**

```
ServiceID Activity_type       Start_date  End_date
1         Long Day Care       12/03/2012  12/03/2020
1         Family Day Care     12/03/2012  12/03/2020
2         Vacation Care       12/05/2012  12/03/2020
2         Before School Care  12/05/2012  12/03/2020
3         Long Day Care       12/09/2012  12/03/2020
3         Vacation Care       12/09/2012  12/03/2020
3         After School Care   12/09/2012  12/03/2020
```

Now I want to display blank `Activity_type` when service doesn't have Activity like get all the distinct `Activity_type` and if the service don't have that activity then display the record with `ServiceId , Start_date, End_Date` and a blank `Activity_type`. I want total rows for each service = total count of distinct Activity type.

Output should be like below. for each service has five rows as total count of distinct activity type is 5 here.

```
ServiceID Activity_type       Start_date  End_date
1         Long Day Care       12/03/2012  12/03/2020
1         Family Day Care     12/03/2012  12/03/2020
1                             12/03/2012  12/03/2020
1                             12/03/2012  12/03/2020
1                             12/03/2012  12/03/2020
2         Vacation Care       12/05/2012  12/03/2020
2         Before School Care  12/05/2012  12/03/2020
2                             12/05/2012  12/03/2020
2                             12/05/2012  12/03/2020
2                             12/05/2012  12/03/2020
3         Long Day Care       12/09/2012  12/03/2020
3         Vacation Care       12/09/2012  12/03/2020
3         After School Care   12/09/2012  12/03/2020
3                             12/09/2012  12/03/2020
3                             12/09/2012  12/03/2020
```

Any help???

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure it could be made in a more efficient way, but the simplest way should be to make a cartesian product between the `ServiceID` and `Activity_Type` to get all combinations, and then `LEFT JOIN` to the data table to get the values that actually exist.

In TSQL, that would be;

```
SELECT s.ServiceID, ISNULL(t.Activity_Type,'') Activity_Type, 
       s.Start_date, s.End_date
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ServiceID,Start_date, End_date FROM Table1) s
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Activity_Type FROM Table1) a
  ON 1=1
LEFT JOIN Table1 t
  ON s.ServiceID = t.ServiceID
 AND a.Activity_Type = t.Activity_Type
ORDER BY ServiceID, Activity_Type DESC
```

The only really RDBMS dependent part is `ISNULL` that for example in MySQL is called `IFNULL`.

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3de90/2).

Answer (score 0):

If the Activity_type column is defined as allowing `null` values, then you can just skip that value when doing your `INSERT`.  For example, in MySQL:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (ServiceID, Start_date, End_date) values (1, '2012-12-03', '2020-12-03');
```

Other databases may have slightly different default formats for specifying a date, but the idea should be the same.

Comment: @Sivakumar: it isn't the clearest question and it isn't obvious that there is more than one table involved.  I decided to answer the simplest possible interpretation of the question, in case it turns out that that is all the OP is asking.